# API - Multiple requests vs separating user roles

Tags: api, rest, single-page-application

I'm working on the frontend of a single page application and I have to list a number of students. Each student is attached to a certain `user_id` This is what the API returns for all user roles (superadmin, admin, professor, student) when I perform `GET /students`:

```
{
  address: null
  class_id: 184
  class_name: "I B"
  date_of_birth: null
  first_name: "first"
  gender: null
  grade: 1
  id: 192
  last_name: "last"
  nationality: null
  place_of_birth: null
  ranking_by_class: 0
  ranking_by_school: 0
  registration_number: null
  user_id: 238
}
```

I'm working on the superadmin role at the moment where I'm in need of extra data from each student (`subscription_type`), which is only available on `GET /users/:id`

So when I'm listing 20-30 students on a page via `GET /students/`, in order to get the `subscription_type`, I'll also need to do 20-30 extra requests, one for each student.

I talked to the API guy about this and I was told that including the extra data into `students` "is not the RESTful way of doing it", "it will slow down the response times even more" and that "30 extra requests weigh less than a big chunk".

I don't know anything about working on an API, so I can't really have a say, but am I crazy to think that 30 requests on a page load is ludicrous?

So what next? Do I go ahead and perform the extra requests? Should he separate the responses for each user role and include just the things I need for each role? What is the **correct way** of handling this?

Comment: Without knowing the actual API in question the important factor in REST performance wise is component interactions. More interactions can cause end user reduced performance as well as high latency issues. So without having any first hand knowledge of the API its may be a matter of "doing what your told and not what's right".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While strictly speaking the API guy is correct, following the RESTful gospel too strictly can lead to inefficiencies like the 1+N problem created by the purist implementation.  A key concept in RESTful design is that resources do not have to map directly to domain objects.  When designing resources one must look at the usage scenarios. In the super admin scenario, it sounds like when the client requests a collection of `students` and it also typically or always needs data from `users`, specifically `subscription_type`. The object model is clearly normalized as it should be, but that does not say that the resources must be, or must always be.

There are a couple of different patterns I have used to make similar scenarios more efficient.  Which (if either) apply depends on how the resources are consumed by clients.

### Composite Resource

This is the combination of all or part two or more domain objects (e.g. `student` and `user`) into a single resource.

Since all `students` are presumably also `users`, you could include all or part of the user data in the student resource as appropriate.

`GET /students`

```
{
  address: null
  class_id: 184
  class_name: "I B"
  date_of_birth: null
  first_name: "first"
  gender: null
  grade: 1
  id: 192
  last_name: "last"
  nationality: null
  place_of_birth: null
  ranking_by_class: 0
  ranking_by_school: 0
  registration_number: null
  user_id: 238
  subscription_type: "foo"
}
```

### Related Resources

(Similar to another response) This is a technique where the client can indicate that it wants a related resource included in the response.  This is particularly useful in "has a" type relationship in the domain model.  It allows the client to essentially *lazy load* or *eager load* the resource.

`GET /students`

```
{
  address: null
  class_id: 184
  class_name: "I B"
  date_of_birth: null
  first_name: "first"
  gender: null
  grade: 1
  id: 192
  last_name: "last"
  nationality: null
  place_of_birth: null
  ranking_by_class: 0
  ranking_by_school: 0
  registration_number: null
  user_id: 238
}
```

`GET /students?include_user=true`

```
{
  address: null
  class_id: 184
  class_name: "I B"
  date_of_birth: null
  first_name: "first"
  gender: null
  grade: 1
  id: 192
  last_name: "last"
  nationality: null
  place_of_birth: null
  ranking_by_class: 0
  ranking_by_school: 0
  registration_number: null
  user_id: 238
  user:
  {
   id: 238
   subscription_type: "foo"
   ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here, that shouldn't be tied together - 
One is the data returned for each user for the index call (/students), and the other is the authorization process that should determine which data a certain user can be exposed to.

Regarding the data issue - I don't think there's a specific rule to follow. It totally depends on your app's requirements. If the subscription_type field is usually unnecessary, you may consider passing a query parameter ('include_extra_data=1' for example) to indicate that you need it on the specific request, where by default it won't be returned.

Regarding the authorization issue - This should be totally disconnected from the data your asking on your request. The server should be able to determine which data is visible to the user according to the user id. (you can check out the [CanCan gem][1]](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) as a possible solution).

So, combining the two issues, any type of user should be able to make the '/students' request with or without the 'include_extra_data' flag. If the server find the user unauthorized to see the extra data, you can choose one of 2 options - Either return only the data the user is allowed to see, or return a '401 unauthorized' response.

Both ways are valid, and affect the way you deal with the response on your client app.
(I, personally, prefer the later, as it's more descriptive for the client).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: When I said separation, I meant separation of data. So depending on the user role determined by the auth_token which is included in each request, the API could return a different set of data for each role. So the superadmin will include user_id and subscription_type and other user data, while the same request made by the admin will include just the personal data. Or does it all have to be the same?